# constexpr instances of class that usually have non-constexpr behavior in the destructor, in C++20

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr

I would like to be able to create `constexpr` values for a type that usually has a non-trivial destructor.  Unfortunately, I'm using C++20, so don't have `if consteval`.  Here is a minimal working example that is accepted by gcc 12.2.1 and clang++ 15.0.7, but I'm not sure if it's legal:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <string.h>

struct secret {
  int value_;
  constexpr secret(int value) : value_(value) {}
  constexpr ~secret() {
    if (!std::is_constant_evaluated())
      explicit_bzero(&value_, sizeof(value_));
  }
};

constexpr secret my_secret = 5;
secret my_destroyed_secret = 6;
```

My questions are:

1. Is it legal to call a function like `explicit_bzero` from within a `constexpr` destructor?  Since the `if` in the destructor is not `constexpr`, it seems like it should be illegal.
2. If it is legal, then why?
3. If it is not legal, then is there any other way to accomplish why I want--basically clobber any destroyed value that wasn't `constexpr` constructed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this code legal? Since the if in the destructor is not constexpr, it seems like it should be illegal.

> If it is legal, then why?

Yes, it is. Using `std::is_constant_evaluated` without `constexpr` in an `if` is the only correct way to use it.

It is supposed to tell you whether the evaluation of `std::is_constant_evaluated()` (and the expression containing it) is part of evaluation as a constant expression (i.e. compile-time evaluated expression) or not. If you call it inside a condition of a `if constexpr` then it is always evaluated as constant expression and can only ever be `true`, because the condition of `if constexpr` is required to be *in itself* a constant expression, regardless of whether or not the whole `if` statement is evaluated as part of another constant expression.

That this seems to confuse people is one of the reasons that `if consteval` was introduced in C++23 to replace `std::is_constant_evaluated`. See [the paper](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p1938r3.html#the-if-constexpr-stdis_constant_evaluated-problem) which proposed `if consteval` for C++23.

Comment: I think you are commenting on a part of my code that wasn't really in question, so I updated the question slightly.  My question is not whether it is valid to call `if (!std::is_constant_evaluated())`, which is obviously valid code, but rather whether I can call a function such as `explicit_bzero` inside a `constexpr` destructor, and if so why.

Comment: @user3188445 If you are using `std::is_constant_evaluated()` then I assume you know what it does, right? I am not sure why you are surprised then that it is legal. `if (!std::is_constant_evaluated())` prevents you from ever evaluating `explicit_bzero` during compile-time evaluation.

Comment: I see, so the point is that the `if` without `constexpr` is nonetheless `constexpr` evaluated whenever the destructor itself is `constexpr` evaluated, and so that means the `explicit_bzero` is never considered for compilation.  Indeed, `if (value_ != 5)` also seems to work, so I guess the answer is that `constexpr` is smarter than I thought.